# What is the plural of "il miglior fabbro"?

Tags: translation

What is the plural of "il miglior fabbro", the famous epigraph of The Waste Land? Also, what exactly does it mean-- including connotations? (i.e. is it archaic?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Il miglior fabbro* in itself may mean both “the better smith” and “the best smith”. In Italian *miglior(e)* is both a comparative and a superlative form of *buono* (good). Probably the interpretation as “best” is the one an Italian reader would spontaneously give, out of context.

There is a rich context, though. Eliot takes *miglior fabbro* from Dante, whose words and images recur in *The Waste Land*. In the XXVI canto of Purgatory, Dante meets Guido Guinizelli, a poet he looked at as a master. But Guido turns Dante's attention to another soul, that of Provençal poet Arnaut Daniel, saying that he *fu miglior fabbro del parlar materno*, that is, “[he was] a better craftsman of his mother-tongue” (translation by Dorothy L. Sayers).

So, *miglior fabbro* are indeed ancient words, but are still in normal use. You might still say, talking about two artisans, that *Mario è un miglior fabbro rispetto a Luigi* (but *...un fabbro migliore...* would sound more colloquial).

The plural form would simply be *i migliori fabbri*.

Comment: May I ask why are you interested in the plural?

Comment: Thanks. It's for an acknowledgment section of a work where I'm indebted to several "better smiths".

Comment: I see, @Dwagg, thanks.